# How do I specify an interface return type while still remaining dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I'm about flipped upside down here

What I'm trying to do is create a bit of a factory that works on different types of tickets. So I've create an ITicket interface that has a couple signatures like

```
GetOpen(); 
GetById(int id);
```

Now, these methods need to return an instance or a list of instances of the same ticket type, so i thought i'd have the interface look like this

```
List<ITicket> GetOpen();
ITicket GetById(int id);
```

So in practice, I hoping to create the factory method like this:

```
public static List<ITicket> GetOpen(ITicket ticket)
{
   return ticket.GetOpen();
}
```

Ok, now for example, I went back to my class MocRequest and implemented the List GetOpen() method like this:

```
public List<MocRequest> GetOpen()
{
   //implementation grabs a bunch of MocTickets out of the database 
   and converts them into instances of the MocTicketClass and returns them
}
```

I get an error saying this isn't a valid implementation because the return type is MocRequest instead of ITicket. I thought that MocRequest IS A ITicket at this stage, in hindsight I guess it's a bit circular so it doesn't work. The return type needs to be MocRequest so that it can still be used.

I've experimented with making the interface into something more like `ITicket<T>` but then I still have to specify the ticket class type in the factory which kind of defeats the purpose.

So the objective here was to create a single static method in the factory that would handle this stuff. Am I going about this right way? How do I make this work? Or am I still stuck making multiple methods to handle them? TIA

Comment: Is this for testing? Moc leads me to believe that it might be, and if so, there are other approaches you can use here.

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to conceptualize how this is going to work, so alternate solutions would also be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MocRequest` may be an `ITicket`, but that doesn't make a `List<MocRequest>` a `List<ITicket>`.

If you return a `List<MocRequest>` where a `List<ITicket>` is expected, a user of your API might use the resulting list and add an `ITicket` that is not a `MocRequest`. What will the `List<MocRequest>` do in that case? It will break, right?

Therefore, the compiler insists on you returning a `List<ITicket>`.

In general, it's not adviseable to return `List<T>`, because it's not evident whether you're returning a copy of something internal or a reference to the actual internal list. Better declare the return type as `IEnumerable<ITicket>`, which basically means that you just return the tickets, not a writeable list object. (The user of your API is free to insert those tickets into a list of his/her own.)

*For more info on how to return the enumeration, we'll need to get more information about what the tickets look like after being fetched from the DB. Are they in a list or do you construct that list etc.?*

Comment: The focus here isn't so much the list (although I appreciate the point you made here). I'm trying to write a single method that basically accepts anything that has implemented the ITicket interface and returns the 'type' that it was fed. Why interface? Because we're going to be attaching this interface to things that do not necessarily inherit from the parent Ticket class.

Comment: To answer the italics, it depends on the ticket making the request. One of my constructors takes a ticket id. The service knows what type of ticket it is attempting to construct based on the TicketTypeID and returns the appropriate DTO for the calling ticket type object. Each ticket does have SOME common info (created date, created by, etc...) but the rest is very specific to the ticket which is why my factory needs to return the actual ticket type

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: I think the main question is whether you need to access any type-specific members of the returned object. Do you know which factory you're calling (meaning that each of them can have a different return type in its factory method signature), or do you just call some factory and know you'll get back an `ITicket` (which can be implemented by different classes depending on the current factory; you just cannot/do not need to distinguish when calling the factory)?

Comment: That's a good thought. I think yes, I would need to access them. One example would be a Search method that returns back a collection of itself that meets a criteria, but I suppose I could just remove that from the factory and add it as a static method of that particular class... let me chew on that for a while